# React native skia application using old value of state

Tags: react-native, canvas, state, skia

I've created a simple canvas drawing app using React Native and Skia, which works for the most part, but isn't saving drawing strokes correctly.  It's based loosely off of these [two](https://medium.com/react-native-rocket/building-a-hand-drawing-app-with-react-native-skia-and-gesture-handler-9797f5f7b9b4) [articles](https://blog.notesnook.com/drawing-app-with-react-native-skia/), with the thought being that I could simplify the implementation since a.) Skia already has a `touchHandler` facility so I don't need Gesture Handler, and b.) I should be able to leverage the `useState` hook instead of a state handler like zustand.

The problem I'm running into is that the `paths` state variable is getting updated appropriately (as demonstrated by the `useEffect` console log output) on the first touch event, but appears to be empty on each subsequent touch event. The net effect is that I can draw a series of paths but only the last one is preserved and displayed on the canvas.

My dev environment is Windows using *react-native-cli* instead of *expo*.  Node is installed via nvm-windows.  Project was bootstrapped using `react-native init <project-name>` and launched via `npx react-native run-android`  I modified *App.tsx* to import StateTest from a file containing the code below.  I can reproduce the behavior on a physical Pixel 5 and on an Android Studio virtual device.  Relevant versions are:

```
NPM 9.2.0
@shopify/react-native-skia 0.1.172
react-native 0.71.1
```

Here's the code; I'm using:

```js
import {
    Canvas,
    Path,
    Skia,
    Group,
    useTouchHandler,
  } from "@shopify/react-native-skia";
  import { useState, useRef, useCallback, useEffect } from 'react';

  export const StateTest = () => {
    let workingPath = [];

    const [ displayPaths, setDisplayPaths ] = useState([])
    const [ paths, setPaths ] = useState([]);

    const onDrawingStart = useCallback(({ x, y }) => {
        workingPath = [`M ${x} ${y}`];
    });

    const onDrawingActive = useCallback(({ x, y }) => {
        if (!workingPath){
            return;
        }
        workingPath.push(`L ${x} ${y}`);
      });
   
    const onDrawingFinished = useCallback(() => {
        if (!workingPath){
            return;
        }
        savePaths();
        workingPath = [];
    });

    const touchHandler = useTouchHandler({
        onActive: onDrawingActive,
        onStart: onDrawingStart,
        onEnd: onDrawingFinished,
      });

    /* I thought maybe the problem was with the touchHandler operating on
       an old copy of state, so I pulled that code out here, which didn't
       fix the problem; that's not surprising, since the callback would
       necessarily be operating on the same version of state as the
       touchHandler
    */
    const savePaths = useCallback(() => {
        let localPath = [...paths];
        console.log('before:');
        console.log(localPath);
        localPath.push(workingPath.join(" "));
        console.log('after:');
        console.log(localPath);
        setPaths([...localPath]);
    });
    
    const drawPaths = useCallback(() => {
      console.log("setting displaypaths from:");
      console.log(paths);
      setDisplayPaths(
        <Group>
        {paths.map((p) => 
        <Path key={p} path={p} color="red" style="stroke" strokeWidth={4} />
        )}
        </Group>
      )
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("paths have been updated:");
        console.log(paths);
        drawPaths();
    }, [paths])

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("paths have been drawn:");
        console.log(displayPaths);
    }, [displayPaths])

    return (
        <Canvas style={{ flex: 1 }} onTouch={touchHandler}>
        {displayPaths}
        { /* This may be related; I couldn't get anything to display using the array map
             here, so I created the drawPaths() function and inserted {displayPaths}
             above, which seems to work except for the problem with outdated state.
          paths.map(p => {
            //console.log(`mapped |${p.toSVGString()}|`);
            <Path key={p.toSVGString()} path={p} color="red" style="stroke" strokeWidth={10} />
          }
        ) */ }
      </Canvas>
    );
  };
```

The debug output looks like this.  I started the app and made two finger swipes on the canvas.

```
 LOG  before:
 LOG  []
 LOG  paths have been updated:
 LOG  ["M 283.6363636363636 233.45454545454547 L 283.6363636363636 233.45454545454547 L 283.6363636363636 233.45454545454547  <elided for space>"]
 LOG  setting displaypaths from:
 LOG  ["M 283.6363636363636 233.45454545454547 L 283.6363636363636 233.45454545454547 L 283.6363636363636 233.45454545454547 <elided for space>"]
 LOG  paths have been drawn:
 LOG  <Group><Path color="red" path="M 283.6363636363636 233.45454545454547 L 283.6363636363636 233.45454545454547 <elided for space>" strokeWidth={4} style="stroke" /></Group>
 LOG  before:
 LOG  []
 LOG  paths have been updated:
 LOG  ["M 141.45454545454547 240.72727272727272 L 141.45454545454547 240.72727272727272 L 141.45454545454547 240.72727272727272  <elided for space>"]
 LOG  setting displaypaths from:
 LOG  ["M 141.45454545454547 240.72727272727272 L 141.45454545454547 240.72727272727272 L 141.45454545454547 240.72727272727272 <elided for space>"]
 LOG  paths have been drawn:
 LOG  <Group><Path color="red" path="M 141.45454545454547 240.72727272727272 L 141.45454545454547 240.72727272727272 <elided for space>" strokeWidth={4} style="stroke" /></Group>
```

As you can see, the first input updated the paths or the `useEffect` wouldn't have output the 'paths have been updated' message, but on the second input, the paths array is empty when the `touchHandler`'s `onEnd` event calls my `onDrawingFinished` callback.  I would expect that by the time I draw the second path, it would observe the updated state, but I'm not confident in my understanding of react internals, so it's entirely possible I've just overlooked some facet of `useState` or Skia.